# How to add annotation @Deprecated in Java source code generated by thrift automatically?

Tags: java, annotations, thrift, deprecated

I want to declare some field or interface is deprecated. So I need a way to add this annotation automatically with **thrift java code generator**.

Comment: how would some tool know automatically what is deprecated?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thrift is a language that compiles to other languages. It would be deprecated because it's declared deprecated somehow in the source code. They are just asking if there's a way to declare something as deprecated in Thrift.

Comment: @4castle Thanks for the explanation